# column names vertical but data related to them segregated horizontally

Tags: pandas

I have a data where column names are placed vertically but data realted to those column names is placed horizontally as shown in the example below:

%========================================================================

% Column #1
% Column #2
% Column #3
% Column #4
% Column #5
% Column #6
% Column #7
% Column #8
% Column #9
%========================================================================

0        7.2606     0      0       0       0       0       0       0.719683
1        9.0189     0      0       0       0       0       0       0.911514
2        11.0891    0      0       0       0       0       0       1.12339
3        10.0541    0      0       0       0       0       0       1.01546
4        9.26533    0      0       0       0       0       0       0.887908
5        7.63081    0      0       0       0       0       0       0.76277

so entries 0,1,2,3 etc belong to Column#1 and next ones to Column#2 and so on, how can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to write your own function to extract the columns `names` and the number of `skiprows` for the [`Pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method:

**Example**

```
import re

def get_skiprow_and_names(filepath):
    names = []
    border_count = 0
    skiprows = 0
    with open(filepath) as f:
        while border_count < 2:
            line = f.readline()
            skiprows += 1
            if re.match('%=+', line):
                border_count+=1
            elif re.match('^%\s.*', line):
                names.append(re.findall('^%\s(.*)', line)[0])
    return skiprows, headers

skiprows, names = get_headers_skiprows('filepath.txt')

# print(skiprows)
# 12
# print(names)
# ['Column #1', 'Column #2', 'Column #3', 'Column #4', 'Column #5', 'Column #6', 'Column #7', 'Column #8', 'Column #9']

df = pd.read_csv('filepath.txt', skiprows=skiprows, names=names, sep='\s+')
```

[out]

```
   Column #1  Column #2  Column #3  Column #4  Column #5  Column #6  Column #7  Column #8  Column #9
0          0    7.26060          0          0          0          0          0          0   0.719683
1          1    9.01890          0          0          0          0          0          0   0.911514
2          2   11.08910          0          0          0          0          0          0   1.123390
3          3   10.05410          0          0          0          0          0          0   1.015460
4          4    9.26533          0          0          0          0          0          0   0.887908
5          5    7.63081          0          0          0          0          0          0   0.762770
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works after small modifications, i think you by mistake mentioned skip_rows as skiprows and headers as names in few of the rows.